# Replacing Pre defined object with user defined object

Tags: java, object

In System class there is a object 'in' of `InputStream` class. 
I want to replace it by my own object .
Let the object is 'IS'.
I want to implement it as

```
java.util.Scanner sc=new java.util.Scanner(IS);
String a=sc.nextLine();
```

What should I do?

Comment: [`System.setIn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)) ?

Comment: What you ask is unclear. You want to replace `System.in` to do what (or if you prefer, what do you want to be read)???

Comment: Nothing just experiment.

Comment: You don't need to replace the System.in stream in order to be able to read from another input stream using a Scanner. Just pass the other input stream as argument to the scanner, instead of passing System.in.

Comment: If I have to replace it by my own object ,what can I do.

Comment: You got the answer 8 minutes ago, in the first comment, with a link pointing at the method documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS)));
String a = sc.nextLine();
```